# SSH: Send remote command to local background

Tags: shell, ssh, tcpdump

So I have a problem similar to [how to send ssh job to background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184717/how-to-send-ssh-job-to-background).

I have a windows c# program automated to execute tcpdump on a remote linux os using http://sshnet.codeplex.com/.  I'm trying to execute tcpdump on the remote linux and leave it running after I disconnect.

I've been doing a lot of debugging using plink, but cannot seem to achieve the desired result.  I've tried:

```
plink root@10.5.1.1 bash -c "tcpdump -i eth0 -w test.cap"
```

but it holds the sshclient until I ctrl+C (not going to work for automated solution).  I've also tried variations of:

```
plink root@10.5.1.1 bash -c "tcpdump -i eth0 -w test.cap &"
```

but either the command is not executed at all (test.cap does not exist) or is terminated immediately (test.cap contains 1 line).  During testing, I've left a ping going, so the capture should have  *somthing*...

The previously mentioned link solves the problem with **screen**, but the remote linux os is not configurable and does not have **screen**.  Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: None of these solutions worked for me, remotely executing tcpdump on a Fedora machine. However, if the tcpdump command is encapsulated by a bash script, the script can be executed via an ssh command remotely and complete as expected.

Comment: As much as I would like to have done that, the remote machine in my case was a read-only embedded OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem while starting a remote application.  This pattern worked for me on Debian servers:

```
ssh root@server "nohup /usr/local/bin/app -c cfg &; exit"
```

*addition:*  for another test the above didn't work, ie. the command didn't start on the remote server. Adding a command that returns successfully before the exit seems to work.

```
ssh root@server "nohup /usr/local/bin/otherapp &; w; exit"
```

Answer (score 6):

In the latter case, your `tcpdump` process is probably being aborted when you disconnect.  Try:

```
plink root@10.5.1.1 bash -c "nohup tcpdump -i eth0 -w test.cap &"
```

See the manpage for [`nohup`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup).  You may also want to consider redirecting stdout and stderr to a file or `/dev/null` to prevent `nohup` from writing output to a file:

```
plink root@10.5.1.1 bash -c "nohup tcpdump -i eth0 -w test.cap >/dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but neither worked. When I run __ps -ef__ on 10.5.1.1, tcpdump is not running. Also, when I just pipe the output of the tcpdump instead of using the built in writer ('>' instead of '-w'), the file is created, but is completely empty. Maybe that helps?

Comment: It sounds like `tcpdump` may just be resisting running in the background, so it's dying. Usually `nohup` deals with those kinds of programs. Offhand, I can't think of any other options that might work for you, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation:
(on windows machine) i wanted to create a ms batch script to open an SSH connection to a raspberry pi and execute a local script in the background.
I found that combining both Raj's and fahd's answers did the trick for me:

my ms batch script:

```
plink -load "raspberry Pi" -t -m startCommand.txt
```

the content of **startCommand.txt** is as follows:

```
nohup /home/pi/myscript >/dev/null 2>&1 &
w
exit
```

The ">/dev/null 2>&1 " is important!
I found out (the hard way) that the RPi's SDcard kept getting full by an extremely large nohup.out file (and with a full SDcard, the RPi couldn't even login properly)

reasoning:

I used the -load to load a saved session in PuTTY (i do this because i am authenticating with public/private keys instead of passwords, but this should be the same as simply typing in the host)

then -t (as recommended by Raj)

then -m to load a list of commands in that file

without the parameter "-t" and without the "w" and "exit", my batch script would just run, not execute 'myscript' and close again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I had a scrip in which I had nohup tcpdump .... & . I could not use ssh to run it as it dies when the ssh finished. The solution I came up with was super simple. I just added sleep 5 to the end of my script and it works just fine. It seems tcpdump needs some seconds to go to background safely before you exit even with nohup.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I found that the "-t" option seems to be important to nohup. I found the nohup wasn't taking affect without the "-t" option.

`ssh -t user@remote 'nohup tcpdump -i any -w /tmp/somefile &>/dev/null & sleep 2'`

Answer (score 0):

I think that I've nailed it, at least in IBM AIX

I'm using

```
ssh -tq user@host "/path/start-tcpdump.ksh"
```

(authentication is done by publick key).
I was having inconsistent results using simple "nohup tcpdump .... &", sometimes it worked, sometimes it did not, sometimes it even blocked and I had to disconnect the session.
So far, this is working ok, I can't really say WHY it is working, but it is...

This is my start-tcpip.ksh

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
HOST=$(uname -n)
FILTER="port not 22"
(tcpdump -i en1 -w $HOST-en1.cap $FILTER >/dev/null 2>&1 ) &
sleep 2
(tcpdump -i en2 -w $HOST-en2.cap $FILTER >/dev/null 2>&1 ) &
sleep 2
exit 0
```

Comment: What is `start-tcpip.ksh`?  You only mention `start-tcpdump.ksh` in your command.